# How to fix setInterval bugg?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout, setinterval

I am having a h1 with v-for and i am writing out things from my array ,it looks like this:

```
 <h1
        v-for="(record, index) of filteredRecords"
        :key="index"
        :record="record"
        :class="getActiveClass(record, index)"
      >
        <div :class="getClass(record)">
         
          <strong v-show="record.path === 'leftoFront'"
            >{{ record.description }}
          </strong>
          
        </div>
      </h1>
```

as you can see i am bindig a class  (**getActiveClass(record,index)**   --> passing it my record and an index)

This is my getActiveClass method:

```
getActiveClass(record, index) {
      this.showMe(record);

      return {
        "is-active": index == this.activeSpan
      };
    }
```

i am calling a function called **showMe** passing my record to that   and  thats where the problem begins
the showMe method is for my setInterval so basically what it does that i am having multiple objects in my array and  it is setting up the interval so when the record.time for that one record is over then it switches to the next one.  Looks like this:

```
 showMe(record) {
     console.log(record.time)
      setInterval(record => {

        if (this.activeSpan === this.filteredRecords.length - 1) {
          this.activeSpan = 0;
        } else {
          this.activeSpan++;
        }
      }, record.time );
    },
```

this activeSpan is making sure that the 'is-active' class (see above)  is changing correctly.

Now my problem is that  the record.time is not working correctly when i print it out it gives me for example if iam having two objects in my array it console logs me both of the times .
So it is not changing correctly to its record.time   it is just changing very fastly, as time goes by it shows just a very fast looping through my records .

Why is that? how can i set it up correctly so that when i get one record its interval is going to be the record.time (what belongs to it) , and when a record changes  it does again the same (listening to its record.time)

FOR EXAMPLE :

```
filteredRecords:[
{
description:"hey you",
time:12,
id:4,
},
{
description:"hola babe",
time:43,
id:1
},


]
```

it should display as first the  "hey you"  text ,it should be displayed for 12s,  and after the it should display the "hola babe" for 43 s.

thanks

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`

Comment: thats not helping sir,  it keeps changing fast even, not listening to its record.time, i console.log it out and it gives me 12000 , 43000  which are their times in millisec so that is correct is just not working properly

Comment: also i need the setInterval because  i am swapping each of them when the time is over not just one setting them out.

Comment: Can you mutate the data? instead of constantly running intervals foreach entry I'd add a property to your data to keep track of which record is currently displayed. Something like `currentlyActive: true`. Then you only need one "global" interval in your component instead of managing multiple ones

Comment: its completely impossible right now i am getting the data from my rails API if i want to give another property all of my data will be lost, i need to manage this problem without manipulating my data

Comment: Could you add a simple codesandbox with the code in question? It would help immensly to restructure the code a little bit. You don't have to add your API-Call, just enter some example JSON-data :) This should be definitely solvable without mutating your data if that's your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template>
  <h1 ...>{{ filteredRecords[index].description }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
{
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      // ...
    };
  },

  methods: {
    iterate(i) {
      if (this.filteredRecords[i]) {
        this.index = i;
        window.setTimeout(() => iterate(i + 1), this.filteredRecords[i].time * 1000);
      }
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.iterate(0);
  },
}
</script>
```

How about this? Without using `v-for`.